# Historical airline schedules?

Tags: united-states, aircraft, sources, transportation

I am looking for historical airport schedules from the US and Canada from after WWII. For example, I would really like to see a flight schedule (or schedules) from New York from around 1948. Any ideas where I might find this data either on the internet or in an old publication?

Comment: Rut row george, you screwed the pooch by asking for reference sources.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for references.

Comment: I perceive this as a request for primary /canonical sources, and I would vote to leave it open.

Comment: I did find an EBAY link for "Vintage 1948 TTA Trans Texas Airways Timetable Flight Schedule Route Map"

Answer (score 2):

Ebay is a good resource. You can find examples there on a regular basis.
[image]

[image]

[image]